# Do some shooting stars NOT travel in a straight line?

Tags: meteor

I saw what I assumed was a shooting star on December 21 (or 22) 2020 that moved in a straight line and then abruptly turned in an arc perpendicular to its original straight path. The brightness and duration was like any other shooting star that I’ve seen, but it’s path was not. Is this common?

Comment: wavy paths have been observed, (they are very rare)  but not sudden turns.  This is more likely to have been two meteors that happened at the same time.